# Distinguishing between Exceptions thrown by Excel Interop operations

Tags: c#, excel, exception, interop, comexception

I am exporting data to Excel from within my C# application, using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` library.

Calling `sheet.Cells[currentRow, 1])` with an invalid `currentRow` value, results in a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` with the message:

```
"Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"
```

and the `ErrorCode` -2146827284

However, I've received the exact same errorcode for ordering Excel to save to a write protected file.

**Is there a way for me to distinguish between the COMExceptions received from Excel, so I can handle them accordingly?**
I would rather not leave my users with "Something went wrong while working with Excel, sorry, sucker."

Comment: I've been working with Excel interop for several years and I have not found a way. Your best bet is to check for potential issues before they occur. I wish there was something better, but to the best of my knowledge there isn't.

Comment: That is quite a frustrating state of affairs. Thanks. Do you want to put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working with Excel interop for several years and I have not found a way. Your best bet is to check for potential issues before they occur. I wish there was something better, but to the best of my knowledge there isn't.

**EDIT**
You can trap different errors within VBA, so Excel itself does distinguish between the various errors, but I believe that .NET roles all of these errors up into a single COMException class which gives you no detailed information.

I found this article detailing the VBA error codes:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146864

Comment: The blame is on Excel, not .NET - If they had defined different `HRESULT` values for different error conditions, then the different errors would be distinguishable in .NET code.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I was a little fuzzy on that. Couldn't tell if Excel was hiding the information or if .NET was losing it (perhaps error information not accessible through the .NET interop?)

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a `COMException` is that it's coming back from the COM side of things. Usually, in COM, error conditions are signalled by the `HRESULT` return value from a particular method not being 0.

That, unfortunately, is the extent of error information built into the COM "contracts". So you get the error value (0x800A03EC is the same value as -2146827284). The .NET side of things has no further information.

Comment: interesting. +1 for knowing about COM